# How use include and use (in code) a README file (or other text) for a .NET project?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a simple project, which includes a README file. I'd like to have the contents that file appear in part of the application. I've added the file to the .csproj file as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\README.md">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

But I'm uncertain how to access the file in my code in order to be able to display it (assuming I've included it in the correct way).

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I've found I can add this to the ItemGroup section:

```
     <EmbeddedResource Include="..\README.md" />
```

then access it in code using

```
var stream = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name + ".README.md"));
```

Would still be nice to be access the README resource more cleanly though.